# How to add a link to an image in Remarkup (Phabricator)

Tags: phabricator

When creating wiki pages in Phabricator's Phriction, I would like to use images as links. So rather than using a normal, textual link like

```
[[ url | this is a link]]
```

I would like to use an image for the link

```
[[ url | {F4711} ]]
```

Unfortunately, Phabricator renders just the text {F4711} and not the image from the file F4711.

Is this possible with Remarkup?
Any workarounds?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is possible in Remarkup. The [official documentation](https://secure.phabricator.com/book/phabricator/article/remarkup/#linking-uris) doesn't mention a way to do it and I've never seen it done, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use `{img https://cdn-images-1.medium.com/fit/c/72/72/1*ZroWAkaLZdsNIBOHSoez3g.jpeg}`

> Syntax is as follows:
>
> `{image <IMAGE_URL>}`
>
> Parameters are also supported, like:
>
> `{image uri=<IMAGE_URI>, width=500px, height=200px, alt=picture of a moose, href=google.com}`
>
> URLs without a protocol are not supported.

see more: https://secure.phabricator.com/D16597

Comment: Well, +1 for creative thinking, but unfortunately it does not solve the problem. 1) The referenced image (F4711) is local to the Phabricator instance. Using a fully qualified IMAGE_URL to address the image will usually not work, because it is blocked by the `security.outbound-blacklist`. 2) Even if the `{img ...}` finally resolves to a displayed image, you still can't embed it into a link as described initially, because it suffers from the same problem as {F4711} - rendered as text.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a patch in https://github.com/phacility/phabricator/blob/master/src/applications/files/markup/PhabricatorEmbedFileRemarkupRule.php#L169

like this:

```
$href = $file->getBestURI();
$sigil = 'lightboxable';
if (isset($options['href'])) {
  $href = $options['href'];
  $sigil = '';
}

$img = phutil_tag('img', $attrs);

$embed = javelin_tag(
  'a',
  array(
    'href'        => $href,
    'class'       => $image_class,
    'sigil'       => $sigil,
    'meta'        => array(
      'phid'     => $file->getPHID(),
      'uri'      => $file->getBestURI(),
      'dUri'     => $file->getDownloadURI(),
      'viewable' => true,
      'monogram' => $file->getMonogram(),
    ),
  ),
  $img);
```

But in this case you cannot set the protocols:

```
{image uri=<IMAGE_URI>, width=500px, height=200px, alt=picture of a moose, href="//google.com"}
```

The reason is, phabricator renders first a `a` Tag with the url from the href attribiute and then the embed `F` Tag.